# Subletting a data frame and facing error message "‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames"

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to make a subset of a data frame and must use the method I specified below. 
My data looks like :

```
NameA   NameB   NameC   Num1   Num2
  A       E       I       1      1 
  B       F       J       5      8 
  C       G       K       6      6 
  D       H       L       8      8
```

The code I have to use is: `df1<- df[df[Num1] == df[Num2]]`

However, every time I run the above code, I get an error msg saying

`Error in Ops.data.frame(df[Num1],df[Num2]) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`

Is there any way I can fix the error? (I can not change the method of doing it). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I believe that what you want is  `df1<- df[df$Num1 == df$Num2, ]`  OR `df[df['Num1'] == df['Num2'], ]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose the row where Num1==Num2

```
df1 <- df[df$Num1 == df$Num2,]
```

You can also use filter

```
library(dplyr)  
df1 <- df %>%
       filter(Num1 == Num2)
```